# sequence number for same text VBA macros

Tags: excel, vba

I am newbie in Macros VBA excel.

I am trying to write short code to display sequence number for same text  VBA macros as shown in the screenshot.  Please help me friends. I tried alot , some help will be really appreciated.

```
| Sequence | Subject |
|----------|---------|
| 1        | hello   |
| 2        | hello   |
| 3        | hello   |
| 1        | Hi      |
| 2        | Hi      |
| 1        | come    |
| 2        | come    |
| 3        | come    |
| 4        | come    |
| 1        | go      |
```

Comment: Is `VBA` a must? This is done through a simple `COUNTIF` usually. If `VBA`, then include your attempt no matter how bad. We were all beginners at some point. Here to help!

Comment: `=COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)` Where `B2` is where your first instance of `Hello` is. Then just drag down. Not this will give the sequence despite the order. If VBA is a requirement, one method would be just recreating this function with VBA (`Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf`)